# Showing a google map in angular-ui modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Trying to load a simple google map within an angular-ui modal. However no luck. The data get's passed in fine, but nothing works in terms of the map... Please help.

```
$modalInstance.opened.then(function() {

var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.834442, -82.3686479),
  zoom: 8
};

  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("eventMap"), mapOptions);
});
```

Inside the modal html:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-5" id="eventMap" style="display: block; height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this in the regular page HTML and worked fine...

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps); an AngularJS directive for Google maps that is very flexible and powerful and easy to use. I've prepared a working demo for your case:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eEtaGH?p=preview

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that issue with all the grayness everywhere starting from the second opening of the overlay?

Comment: I'm not getting your question, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Open the map. It looks good so far. Close it. Open it again. See?

Comment: Use `ng-if='render'` - where `$scope.render` is set to true within your modal controller. Alternatively, use `ng-if='$parent.render'` if `render` is within your parent controller. However, then you will need to set `$scope.render` on your `openModal( )` method

Answer (score 6):

To remove the grayness, according to https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/faq:

> If rendering starts before elements are full size, google maps calculates according to the smaller size. This is most commonly the case with a hidden element (eg, ng-show). To fix this, use "ng-if" instead, as this will wait to attach to the DOM until the condition is true, which should be after everything has rendered fully.

I've modified your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/JetUBY?p=preview to remove the grayness.
Controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, lat, lng) {
    $scope.render = true;
    // code here
}
```

Template:

```
<map ng-if="$parent.render" center="[{{$parent.lat}}, {{$parent.lng}}]" zoom-control="true" zoom="8"> </map>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger 'resize' event. Follow these lines:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("eventMap"), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize', function () {
    // your callback content
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I too ran Into a similar situation, where I am loading a map in an angular modal instance.
 I too searched many places and did't get the correct simple solution for it.
So I gone deeper and found a simple solution for this issue.

**The issue is that, the map is trying to get the div from the modal before it gets loaded**, and the solution is:

In your controller take  a `$timeout` angular parameter,

```
function MyController($scope,$cookies,$modal,$window,roomService,$timeout) {

**** after all your model code is defined ****

$modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("eventMap"),
                myOptions);
    }
    $timeout(function() {
       initialize()
     }, 1000);
});

*** use the time out to make the div load and then call the map ***

}
```

This time out made the map to load perfectly in the modal. A simple solution.