# Angular JS google map rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am facing problem with google map.

Currently map showing like this.
[image]

```html
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

```js
var ngApp = angular.module('ngTest', ['ngResource', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
    ngApp.config(
      ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApiProviders) {
        GoogleMapApiProviders.configure({
          v: '3.17',
          china: true
        });
      }]);
```

What would be the problem.
Please help, thanks

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this problem

Comment: add value `map.zoom = 4` and try

Comment: have set the hight and width for google map?

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions, no luck

Comment: Would be much easier if we could debug in the problem page.

Comment: Try iFrames for google map

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Angular Google Maps - FAQ](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/faq) on maps that are partially rendering:

> If rendering starts before elements are full size, google maps calculates according to the smaller size. This is most commonly the case with a hidden element (eg, ng-show). **To fix this, use "ng-if" instead, as this will wait to attach to the DOM until the condition is true**, which should be after everything has rendered fully.

Angular Google Maps - [Documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) and [Quickstart](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use) might help.

Additionally, this SO post - [Showing a google map in angular-ui modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275977/showing-a-google-map-in-angular-ui-modal) will be quite helpful too.